# How to pass a file array along with other string/int variables in java script to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass `imageArray[]` along with a variable `trackNo`. The `imageArray[]` I can pass it fine with no problem. I'm just uncertain on how to append/include other variables to the `FormData()`

Online I only see examples of people passing only a file array to a php file and never with other information.

```
$('#ad_post_btn').click(function () {
    ad_errmsg = "";

    imageList = myImageList(); //my array of images imageList[]

    console.log(imageList); //display files in imageList[]

    var trackNo = Math.round(Math.random() * (100000 - 1) + 1); // random number

    console.log(trackNo); // shows the random generated number

    var data = new FormData(); 
    var dataString = 'trackno=' + trackNo; //the variable a want to pass along with the array

    for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        data.append('images[]', imageList[i]); //where I store my image files, work fine
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadimage.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
```

I've tried

```
data: data,dataString ,
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can we see myFileList() function?

Comment: data: data+"&dataString =dataString" , you can pass in this way too

Comment: @MarkOverton `function myImageList() {
    return imageList;
}`  anyways my problem was fixed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`data.append('trackno', trackNo);`

You can put this right before or after your for loop.

`.append('key', value)` will allow you to keep adding more fields.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: this worked out fine, thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

```
data.append("key", value);
```

**Source:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects